Pandas second smallest value with condition
How can I add a column to df with second smallest value  for every item just from columns corresponding from dictionary and with condition when calculating second smallest value - if the values in the selected columns are greater than the values in the column 'Col7'?
import pandas as pd
my_dict={'Item1':['Col1','Col3','Col6'],
'Item2':['Col2','Col4','Col6','Col8'],
'Item3':['Col1','Col3','Col6']
        }
df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Col0':['Item1','Item2','Item3'],
            'Col1':[20,25,28],
            'Col2':[89,15,35],
            'Col3':[36,30,96],
            'Col4':[40,108,13],
            'Col5':[55,2,9],
            'Col6':[35,38,27],
            'Col7':[30,20,39],
            })

The result should be:
df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Col0':['Item1','Item2','Item3'],
            'Col1':[20,25,28],
            'Col2':[89,15,35],
            'Col3':[36,30,96],
            'Col4':[40,108,13],
            'Col5':[55,2,9],
            'Col6':[35,38,27],
            'Col7':[30,20,39],
            'second min':[36,108,'NaN']
            })


I would use a custom function to use in groupby.apply and obtain the second largest with numpy.partition:
def get_nth(g, N=2):
    tmp = g.reindex(columns=my_dict.get(g.name))
    return pd.Series(np.partition(tmp.where(tmp.ge(g['Col7'], axis=0)),
                                  N-1, axis=1)[:, N-1], index=g.index)

df['second min'] = (df.groupby('Col0', group_keys=False)
                      .apply(get_nth, include_groups=False)
                    )

Same approach vectorized with a mask crafted using str.get_dummies and merge:
mask = (pd.Series({k: '|'.join(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()})
          .str.get_dummies().astype(bool)
          .reindex(df['Col0']).set_axis(df.index)
       )

tmp = df.drop(columns=['Col0'])

N = 2
df['second min'] = np.partition(tmp.where(mask & tmp.gt(tmp['Col7'], axis=0)),
                                N-1)[:, N-1]

Output:
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  second min
0  Item1    20    89    36    40    55    35    30        36.0
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2    38    20       108.0
2  Item3    28    35    96    13     9    27    39         NaN


I've got error in first option 'TypeError: get_nth() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_groups'. Second option works properly, thank You.

@Евгения you can remove this parameter, it's only for recent pandas versions

You can achieve this by iterating over the dictionary items, selecting columns based on the dictionary values, applying the condition to filter out values greater than those in 'Col7', and then finding the second smallest value for each row:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_dict = {
    'Item1': ['Col1', 'Col3', 'Col6'],
    'Item2': ['Col2', 'Col4', 'Col6', 'Col8'],
    'Item3': ['Col1', 'Col3', 'Col6']
}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col0': ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'],
    'Col1': [20, 25, 28],
    'Col2': [89, 15, 35],
    'Col3': [36, 30, 96],
    'Col4': [40, 108, 13],
    'Col5': [55, 2, 9],
    'Col6': [35, 38, 27],
    'Col7': [30, 20, 39],
})

second_min_values = []

for item, cols in my_dict.items():
    selected_cols = [col for col in cols if col in df.columns and col != 'Col7']
    selected_values = df.loc[df['Col0'] == item, selected_cols].values.flatten()
    selected_values = [val for val in selected_values if val > df.loc[df['Col0'] == item, 'Col7'].values[0]]
    if len(selected_values) < 2:
        second_min_values.append('NaN')
    else:
        second_min_values.append(np.partition(selected_values, 1)[1])

df['second min'] = second_min_values

print(df)


